# Checking network speed through a program

Tags: networking, internet-speed

I am sending some packets of data to some server and I want to estimate how much time its going to take sending 100 packets of data. So, can someone help me calculating network speed through a program.

I am beginner here, so sample code or idea will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I love the calculator on this page:

http://kt2t.us/ethernet_efficiency.html

Comment: I cannot figure it out, how to use it in my way. More specifically I want to write a program that can help me to find download and upload speed

Comment: @rocko I think you need to be WAY more specific about what you're trying to do. The calculator I linked to is great for calculating the theoretical max for an Ethernet LAN with no other traffic on it. For more complicated situations, there are tons of variable factors, most of which there is no way to programmatically determine. So you have to just start sending data as fast as you can, and report how many bits or bytes per second you're successfully transferring. Then take how many bits or bytes you've got left, and divide by the current rate, to estimate time remaining.

Comment: Actually i want to send data to some server from my pc, I know the credentials of that server. So I want to estimate how much time it will take to transfer the data from my pc to that server. Now I don't know how can estimate the upload(sending data) time to server which is password protected, using some script.

Comment: For a first approximation: If the server's on your LAN, divide the amount of data (in bits) by the speed of your LAN connection. If the server's not on your LAN, divide the amount of data (in bits) by the upload speed of your broadband connection. Better approximations will typically require actually starting the data transfer and checking its rate.

Comment: We do not have particular upload speed. So is there any program I can write to get the upload speed.

Answer (score 0):

The tool I prefer is **iftop**. You invoke it as follows,

```
  sudo iftop -i wlan0
```

for instance, and it displays a window like this:

[image]

Comment: i am working on windows and server is also running windows

Comment: @rocko The strict equivalent of iftop for Windows is **ntop**, you can find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntop/